# Why SSIS Excel Destination Editor creates two excel sheets?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am creating a SSIS package to extract information from database and exporting it to an excel.
When I click "New..." the editor creates two sheets "SheetExample" and "SheetExample$".
The package works fine with both names, but I just want to know why it's doing that and what's the difference.

[image: Excel Sheet Name]

Comment: Are the tabs actually in the Sheet when you open it?  I believe the $ indicates a named range or similar, see here for explanation:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540110/why-does-excel-sometimes-put-a-on-sheet-name

Comment: I'm guessing you have a named range in each sheet with the same name as the sheet itself.

Comment: Yes, the tabs are there. Maybe those are the ranges of the input tables?